# How common is bacterial mediated transformation? In plants? In animal cells?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, botany

The most [common method to transform plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_%28genetics%29#Plants) is by soaking plant tissue in cultures of agrobacteria ([this is not their current classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrobacterium)) which transfer DNA into the plants.

Is lateral gene transfer ability like this found a lot in nature?  Is *agrobacterium tumificans* especially good at this or is its use in plant genetics only because this strain is well studied?

Is a method like this used for animal cells at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An early report of conjugative transfer into mammalian cells (CHO cells) is:

> [Waters, VL (2001) Conjugation between bacterial and mammalian cells, Nat. Genet. 29: 375–376.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ng779)

This work used the broad host range plasmid RK2 to mobilise shuttle vectors carrying selectable markers. To rule out transfection DNAse I was added (and in controls this was shown to block transfection by a large amount of vector DNA). In any case, the fact that the transfer of the vector required the presence of the mobilising plasmid is pretty strong evidence for a conjugative mechanism.

There is also more recent evidence for transfer into human cells via Type IV secretion systems: here is a recent example:

> [Fernandez-Gonzalez et al. (2011),Transfer of R388 Derivatives by a Pathogenesis-Associated Type IV Secretion System into both Bacteria and Human Cells. J Bacteriol 193: 6257-6265](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=21908662)

And here is a recent review of the topic:

> [Llosa et al. (2012) New perspectives into bacterial DNA transfer to human cells Trends in Microbiology 20: 355-359.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=22748513)

Answer (score 3):

In animal cells the process is called *transfection*, to differentiate from *transformation* which is the process by which cells become immortalized (cancerous). I'm mainly familiar with mammalian cells, and in these systems some [reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfection) is required to open pores of some sort in the cell membrane to allow the genetic material to enter. Viruses can mediate cellular entry on their own, but I am unaware of any method that uses live bacteria (although this doesn't mean that some specialized method doesn't exist).